# Automated Webpack Project Setup through node

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal

My goal is to let a webpack project be setup through node command crateEntireWepbackProject.js file.

I want to execute commands on the shell from a js file, so I can let them run automatically and later on also include custom specifications for a project.

The js file is not from within webpack, but has the commands to create a wepback project from scratch and makes the installs etc. just by me typing `node createEntireWebpackProject.js`

Comment: You need package.json file to that.

Comment: I mean a external index.js file that sets up the package.json and all other things for me through node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to write it from scratch. The best practice is using [yeoman](http://yeoman.io/). There are a lot of generators with webpack. For example:

```
const Generator = require('yeoman-generator');
const mkdirp = require('mkdirp');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = class extends Generator {
  prompting() {
    this.log('Welcome to the classy example generator!');

    const prompts = [
      {
        type: 'input',
        name: 'name',
        message: 'Name?',
        default: this.appname,
      }];

    return this.prompt(prompts).then((props) => {
      this.props = props;
    });
  }

  default() {
    if (path.basename(this.destinationPath()) !== this.props.name) {
      this.log(
        `Your application must be inside a folder named ${this.props.name}`);
      this.log('I\'ll automatically create this folder.');
      mkdirp(this.props.name);
      this.destinationRoot(this.destinationPath(this.props.name));
    }
  }

  writing() {
    this.createPackageJson();
    this.copyFiles();
    this.fillTemplates();
    this.makeCommands();
  }

  install() {
    this.npmInstall(['bunyan', 'dotenv-safe'], { save: true });
    this.npmInstall(['eslint', 'eslint-config-airbnb-base', 'eslint-plugin-import', 'jest'], { 'save-dev': true });
  }

  createPackageJson() {
    this.fs.extendJSON('package.json', {
      name: this.props.name,
      version: '0.1.0',
      main: 'src/app.js',
      scripts: {
        cs: 'eslint src/* __tests__/*',
        'cs:fix': 'eslint src/* __tests__/* --fix',
        start: 'node src/app.js',
        test: 'npm run cs && jest',
      },
      dependencies: {},
      devDependencies: {},
      engines: {
        node: '^8.1.0',
      },
      private: true,
      jest: {
        testEnvironment: 'node',
        transform: {},
        collectCoverage: true,
      },
    });
  }

  copyFiles() {
    [
      '.dockerignore',
      '.eslintrc.json',
      'src/app.js',
    ].forEach(name => this.fs.copy(this.templatePath(name), this.destinationPath(name)));
  }

  fillTemplates() {
    this.fs.copyTpl(
      this.templatePath('README.md'),
      this.destinationPath('README.md'),
      {
        name: this.props.name,
      });
  }
  makeCommands() {
      this.spawnCommandSync('git' ['init']);
      this.spawnCommandSync('git', ['add', '.']);
      this.spawnCommandSync('git', ['commit', '-am', '"yo scaffolded app"']);
  }
};
```

Comment: To setup the project there are not may commands needed, so I would like to know how I can set it up on my own, as I later on want to read files from photoshop and create the files and set them up with webpack all automated so I will need create my own code. But what do I need to write into js to make it a command line code?

Comment: Fabioo Fabiolous, I updated my answer with an example for you. In `makeCommands` function you can find how you can run command line code in your generator.

Comment: I see, that is great. Do you think my whole process will be covered with this system?

Comment: Any things what you can do in a terminal can be automated by yeoman.